# crontab cambia los datos de PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, debian, crontab

Necesito automatizar el envío de unos datos por eMail. Para ello uso PHPMailer. El mismo script, ejecutado directamente desde la consola, o desde un navegador Web, se ejecuta perfectamente (y sin dejar registro en ningún fichero). Sin embargo, al programarlo con **crontab**, escribe en /var/log/syslog lo siguiente:

```
Mar  4 14:12:01 debian cron[292]: (usuario) RELOAD (crontabs/usuario)
Mar  4 14:12:01 debian CRON[8364]: (usuario) CMD (/usr/bin/php /home/usuario/AxiReport/test.php)
Mar  4 14:12:01 debian CRON[8363]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Mar  4 14:12:18 debian crontab[8370]: (usuario) BEGIN EDIT (usuario)
Mar  4 14:12:25 debian crontab[8370]: (usuario) REPLACE (usuario)
Mar
  4 14:12:25 debian crontab[8370]: (usuario) END EDIT (usuario)
```

Y en /var/log/mail.log (se observa que se han modificado los campos from/to):

```
Mar  4 13:52:01 BRIXDEB sendmail[1191]: unable to qualify my own domain name (BRIXDEB) -- using short name
Mar  4 13:52:01 BRIXDEB sendmail[1191]: 224Cq1iO001191: from=root, size=365, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202203041252.224Cq1iO001191@BRIXDEB>, bodytype=8BITMIME, relay=root@localhost
Mar  4 13:52:01 BRIXDEB sm-mta[1196]: 224Cq1HF001196: from=<root@BRIXDEB>, size=595, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202203041252.224Cq1iO001191@BRIXDEB>, bodytype=7BIT, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Mar  4 13:52:01 BRIXDEB sendmail[1191]: 224Cq1iO001191: to=root, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30365, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (224Cq1HF001196 Message accepted for deli>
Mar  4 13:52:01 BRIXDEB sm-mta[1197]: 224Cq1HF001196: to=<root@BRIXDEB>, ctladdr=<root@BRIXDEB> (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30780, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

La línea de crontab es:

```
00 4 * * * /usr/share/php /var/www/html/Web/test.php
```

¿Cómo es posible que crontab modifique los datos de envío del email?

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: ¿A qué te refires con que *se modifican los datos*? ¿Llega un correo con otros datos?

Comment: Configura PHPMailer para enviar los correos por SMTP en lugar de la función `sendmail()`.